# Cloudant vs JustOneDB - Which one to choose?

Tags: database, cloud, appharbor, cloudant, justonedb

I am trying to decide which add-on DB to use with my application when I deploy it on [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/). I've two choices: [JustOneDB](https://appharbor.com/addons/justonedb) or [Cloudant](https://appharbor.com/addons/cloudant). I am planning to develop a web and mobile application, which will should work with Terabytes of data.

I am searching for the easiest solution to deploy my database, without me needing to partition the DB and the tables. I want a DB that can handle a very large amount of data, but takes the sharding and partitioning architecture building away from the developer.

I also want a solution that will allow me to easily backup my large database and easily restore it.

From what I've read, Cloudant and JustOneDB are the two most popular ones, and those are available as add-ons on AppHarbor for easy deployment.

I need your recommendations on which one I should go with, the cons and pros of each one. I am developing my application in ASP.NET and C# inside Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MyCouch.Cloudant was just released. Except from CouchDb and Cloudant core feature support the [MyCouch.Cloudant NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MyCouch.Cloudant) package adds support for Searches. There will be more Cloudant specific features added to this. It's written in C# and supports .Net40, .Net45 and Windows store apps.

You will find more info about MyCouch [in the GitHub repo](http://github.com/danielwertheim/mycouch).

Answer (score 1):

There's a recent post on the Cloudant blog about using the MyCouch .Net library with Cloudant databases:
https://cloudant.com/blog/how-to-customize-quorum-with-cloudant-using-mycouch/

Cloudant also offers free hosting up to a greater than $5 bill and can work with Apache CouchDB's replication if you want to develop locally and sync it to the cloud for production/deployment. Multi-master replication isn't something many other databases offer.

Best of luck with your application!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably also consider [MongoDB](https://appharbor.com/addons/mongohq) and [RavenDB](https://appharbor.com/addons/ravenhq).

If you're just starting out, your first concern should probably be to find a database that'll let you quickly get started and build the application you have in mind. When the application becomes a success and actually attracts terabytes of data, you can start worrying about how to scale it. If the application is soundly architected, adapting it to use an appropriate datastore should not be a monumental task.

Answer (score 0):

Comment removed by  originator.